# Get JavaScript slideToggle to close active div when opening another one?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, slidetoggle

Here's a demo of what I have so far: http://www.betafreshmedia.com/nathan/coffee.html

I know there are a lot of other questions like this, however, I cannot adapt their syntax to mine as everyone's is pretty different. Here's my jQuery:

```
$(".trigger").click(function() {
$(this).find('ul.coffeetype').slideToggle();
});
```

I want a minimal, straight-forward way to continue using the same class for each div and only allow one to be opened at a time. When you click on a div that's closed, I want the open one to slide out of sight and the new one to drop down in its respective position.

HTML:

```
<div class="trigger">
<img src="images/coffeetype1.png" />
<ul class="coffeetype">
    <li>International</li>
    <li>Regional</li>
    <li>International</li>
    <li>Regional</li>
    <li>International</li>
    <li>Regional</li>
    <li>International</li>
    <li>Regional</li>
    <li>International</li>
    <li>Regional</li>
    <li>International</li>
    <li>Regional</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="trigger">
<img src="images/coffeetype1.png" />
<ul class="coffeetype">
    <li>International</li>
    <li>Regional</li>
    <li>International</li>
    <li>Regional</li>
    <li>International</li>
    <li>Regional</li>
    <li>International</li>
    <li>Regional</li>
    <li>International</li>
    <li>Regional</li>
    <li>International</li>
    <li>Regional</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="trigger">
<img src="images/coffeetype1.png" />
<ul class="coffeetype">
    <li>International</li>
    <li>Regional</li>
    <li>International</li>
    <li>Regional</li>
    <li>International</li>
    <li>Regional</li>
    <li>International</li>
    <li>Regional</li>
    <li>International</li>
    <li>Regional</li>
    <li>International</li>
    <li>Regional</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

It's just the same thing three times in a row right now for demo purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".trigger").click(function() {
        var $el = $(this).find('ul.coffeetype');
        var $opened = $('.toggledDown').not($el);
        $opened.toggleClass('toggledDown');
        $opened.slideToggle();
        $el.toggleClass('toggledDown');
        $el.slideToggle();
    });
});
```

Track the ones that are open and close them before you open the active one.

*EDIT* Added the ".not($el)" so you can still toggle the same menu up and down.

Comment: Oh, is there a way the user can click on the trigger of an open slider again to toggle it shut and get it out of the way, while retaining the functionality you provided for the other sliders? Right now if you do that the open list toggles up and back down, but I want to target the open one separately from the behavior above.

Comment: @Betafresh Media - You just have to add a ".not(...)" to the 'opened' selector.

Comment: This does exactly what I described, except if you have a list down, and you toggle it back up, then drop a different one, BOTH of the lists slide down simultaneously and get caught in an endless loop where they can't all be closed simultaneously.

Comment: @Betafresh Media - you just have to follow the logic... Switching add/removeClass for toggleClass corrects the issue.

Comment: Thank you for putting up with my Javascript illiteracy, you're a life saver

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is correct:-

### JS

```
$(".trigger").hover(function() {
   $(this).find('.coffeetype').slideToggle();
});​
```

### CSS

```
.coffeetype {
    display: none;
}​
```

Refer **[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dVVwB/)**

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to the following:

```
$(".trigger").click(function() {
    $('ul.coffeetype').slideUp();
    $(this).find('ul.coffeetype').slideToggle();
});​
```

This slides all open lists closed first.